# Using nameof for specifying FieldName in Devexpress Gridcontrol binding

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, nameof

I'm using Devexpress Gridcontrol in my application which is developing at quite a rapid pace, and this often involves refactoring, changing property names etc as requirements become more clear / evolve.

Because the property names are hard-coded into a string in the `form.designer.cs` file, this makes it very difficult to pick up with refactoring. I use Resharper and I'm aware you can select the box to search in string literals, but when the text is `Description` or `Manufacturer` this appears hundreds of times in unrelated string literals across my project so to implement this way would be time consuming and frankly a waste of time.

Using the `nameof` operator provides the bridge between specifying field names explicitly, whilst also providing out of box support for refactoring.

Take this snippet from my designer file.

```
// 
// colManufacturer
// 
this.colManufacturer.Caption = "Manufacturer";
this.colManufacturer.ColumnEdit = this.xrefManufacturerSearch;
this.colManufacturer.FieldName = "Manufacturer";
this.colManufacturer.Name = "colManufacturer";
this.colManufacturer.Visible = true;
this.colManufacturer.VisibleIndex = 1;
```

If I replace the `FieldName` attribute to

```
this.colManufacturer.FieldName = nameof(CrossRef.Manufacturer);
```

But now i cannot open the designer for this form, error code 'The designer cannot process unknown name `nameof` at line 125. The code within the method InitializeComponent is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified.

Is there any way of using nameof expressions for Devexpress Field Names?

Comment: What's the compilation error you're receiving?

Comment: @JonathonChase question updated.

Comment: You might be able to declare a constant in a static class like `public const string Manufacturer = nameof(Manufacturer);` and use that, but I'd be a bit concerned that the code would be overridden the first time a developer opens the form in a design view.

Comment: @JonathonChase that's exactly my concern also, as soon as a change is made in the designer these changes are overridden.  I would be sure Devexpress would have thought of something like this? I just couldn't find it in any documentation

Comment: Can you use `nameof` in non-DevExpress controls?

Comment: Have you asked this question at DevExpress ? You can make a ticket there they usually answer the same day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never do any refactoring within the `*.designer.cs` files because of

> The code within the method InitializeComponent is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified

The main reason for this restriction that the [Code-Dom serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-source-code-generation-and-compilation) infrastructure is based on **the restricted subset of С#/VB syntax**. Thus it does not support some specific language features e.g. `nameof`. Take a look at the [CSharpCodeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider) to learn which expressions are allowed or contact the [Visual Studio Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for more information.

Regarding the DevExpres GridControl columns customization, I suggest you take into account the fact that [GridControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3455/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid) supports the [wide range of annotation attributes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/18273/Common-Features/Data-Binding/Data-Annotation-Attributes) which allows you to specify how your columns will be displayed, formatted and validated without design time customization at all. You should only apply the specific annotations at the DTO level and then assign these objects collection directly to the GridControl's DataSource property:

```
public class CrossRef{
    [Display(Name = "MANUFACTURER")]
    [...]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
// ...
gridControl1.DataSource = new BindingList<CrossRef> {
    new CrossRef() { Manufacturer = ... },
    ...
};
```